# Button - random selection

Tags: javascript, button, random

I'm creating a button that will ask 'What is your first name?', then 'Would you like to know your Hogwarts house?' and if the answer is yes, it will say 'name, your Hogwarts house is...'.

I don't know how to add a random selection of the 4 Hogwarts houses.

My HTML is: Sorting Hat
My code is:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cy2Hc.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the 4 possible houses on an array. Then you can select a random item from the array.

Here is a little code example that might help you...

```js
const houses = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
const randomHouse = houses[Math.floor(Math.random() * houses.length)];
console.log(randomHouse);
```